# Insert Record in Database Using Textboxes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to in Insert Record in Database Using Textboxes in JavaScript. I'm referring this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/insert-record-in-database-using-textboxes-in-javascript/  
This solution is working only on internet explorer but I want to use this program for all browser.

Here is my piece of code:

```
function InsertRecord()
        {
            var txtid = document.getElementById('txtid').value;
            var txtname = document.getElementById('txtname').value;
            var txtsalary = document.getElementById('txtsalary').value;
            var txtcity = document.getElementById('txtcity').value;
            if (txtid.length != 0 || txtname.length !=0 || txtsalary.length !=0|| txtcity.length !=0)
            {
                var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
                var connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EmpDetail;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=****;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
                connection.Open(connectionstring);
                var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
                rs.Open("insert into Emp_Info values('" + txtid + "','" + txtname + "','" + txtsalary + "','" + txtcity + "')", connection);
                alert("Insert Record Successfuly");
                txtid.value = " ";
                connection.close();
            }
            else
            {            
                alert("Please Enter Employee \n Id \n Name \n Salary \n City ");

            }
        }
```

If anyone know then let me know that how will be execute this code for all browser.

Comment: Search on google and try if you will be stuck or get error then post question.

Comment: This code is run at internet explorer only but i need to run all browser http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/insert-record-in-database-using-textboxes-in-javascript/

Comment: what is your question? Update your code in question where you are stuck so that we can review.

Comment: See the above coding @PiyushGupta

Comment: I did update your code...now need to wait for solution.

Comment: if You dont know the answer means just leave why are you putting down votes dont be silly for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this on other browsers.

The code is instantiating an `ActiveX` control that connects to the database and that technology is [not supported](http://www.ehow.com/list_6702546_browsers-support-activex_.html) on any browser but Internet Explorer. Actually, the new Microsoft Edge browser doesn't support it either.

So:

1. Only IE supports it
2. Future browsers from Microsoft will not support it
3. The code above contains the username and password to a database which could be a huge security risk.

**Don't do that**, use another technology (like AJAX) to send the info to a backend and write it from there to a database.